# What would be the formula to get the position of a combination, instead of a permutation ,given an index in this example

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let be an array $A = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ of six elements and we want three elements at the time, so the total number of permutations with repetitions will be: $6^3$.
Now to get the position of those permutations, given an index $i$, we use the following formula:

```
word[0] = i % 6
word[1] = (i / 6) % 6
word[2] = (i / 6 / 6) % 6
```

So for index = 0, we will get:

```
word[0] = 0 % 6                =  0
word[1] = (0 / 6) % 6          =  0
word[2] = (0 / 6 / 6) % 6      =  0
```

Which gives the permutation: a a a

But, what would be the formula to get the **position of combinations (combinations have no repetitions)** instead of permutations with repetitions of this example?

Comment: Do you mean combinations with no repetitions (so no repeats are allowed at all)? Does a,b,c count differently from b,a,c?

Comment: If all three accounts - [Mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/345796/mark), [mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/345767/mark) and [mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/345791/mark) - belong to you, it might be good idea to [merge them](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info).

Comment: Combinations have no order, so the notion of position doesn't make sense. A permutation is a bijection from a set to itself. For finite sets, we can deal with the integers $1, \ldots n$, so the notion of position is clear.

Comment: Neither combinations nor permutations have repetition.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old confusingly phrased question brought to the front page by a small edit. Perhaps the OP is no longer interested in the answer. But I think I know what he's asking.

He imagines a list of the three character words built from the six letter alphabet $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and wants to know the position of a particular word in this list when the list is ordered lexicographically.

That's easy. Just imagine that each word is a number in base $6$ using the digits $a=0$, $b=1 ,\ldots$ . Then each word *is* its position (indexing starting from $0$, of course).